# Build dict mapping from multiple text files

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files, glob, string-concatenation

I have multiple *.txt file with an ID and a value, and I want to create a unique dictionary. However, some IDs are repeated in some files, and for those ID, I want to CONCATENATED the values. This is an example of two files (but I have a bunch of files, so I think I need glob.glob):(Notice all the 'values' in a certain file have the same length, so I can add '-' as many times the len(value) is missing.

File 1

```
ID01
Hi 
ID02 
my 
ID03 
ni
```

File 2

```
ID02 
name
ID04 
meet 
ID05 
your
```

Desire Output: (Notice that when there is no repetitive ID, I want to add 'Na' or '-', with the same len(value) to be concatenated) This is my output:

```
ID01 
Hi----
ID02 
myname
ID03 
ni----
ID04 
--meet
ID05 
--your
```

I just want to store the output in a dictionary. Additionally, I guess if I print the file when is open, I could know the order of which files are being opened after the other, right?

This is what I have: (I cannot concatenate my values so far)

```
output={}   
list = []   
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):        
    FI = open(file,'r') 
    for line in FI.readlines():
        if (line[0]=='I'):      #I am interested in storing only the ones that start with I, for a future analysis. I know this can be done separating key and value with '\t'. Also, I am sure the next lines (values) does not start with 'I'
            ID = line.rstrip()
            output[ID] = ''
            if ID not in list:
                list.append(ID)     
        else:
            output[ID] = output[ID] + line.rstrip()

    if seqs_name in list:
        seqs[seqs_name] += seqs[seqs_name]

    print (file)
    FI.close()


print ('This is your final list: ')
print (list) #so far, I am getting the right final list, with no repetitive ID 
print (output) #PROBLEM: the repetitive ID, is being concatenated twice the 'value' in the last file read.
```

Also, How to add the '-' when the ID is not repeated? I would greatly appreciate your help.

To sum up: I cannot concatenate values when the key is repeated in another file.  And if  key are not repeated, I want to add '-' , so I could later print the file name and know in which file certain ID does not have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues with your existing code:

1. `line[0] == 'ID'`: `line[0]` returns a character, so this comparison is always false. Use `str.startswidth(xxx)` instead, to check if a string begins with `xxx`.
2. You are not retrieving the text after the `ID` properly. The easiest way to do this is by calling `next(f)`.
3. You don't need a second list. Also, don't name your variable `list` as it shadows the builtin.

---

```
import collections

output = collections.defaultdict(str)   
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):        
    with open(file, 'r') as f: 
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ID'):   
            try: 
                text = next(f)
                output[line.strip()] += text.strip() + ' ' 
            except StopIteration:
                pass  

print(output)
```

It never hurts to catch the odd exception, using `try-except`.

Comment: What if you want to add '-' or 'Na' when a value is not concatenated?

Comment: @gusa10 one question per thread please ;) You can consider marking this accepted if it helped. As for adding Na, you'll have to get text and then check whether text also starts with ID. That means actual text is missing.

Comment: I am sorry for my naive onto this webpage. Thank you for your answer. Coud you explain me how to get 'NA'. I try with 'if text in output:' but it did not seem to work. Thank you

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you want. Can you open a new question? It'll be easier to explain yourself there. Thank you!